# Analysis electric network with pgRouting

Tags: gis, network-analysis, pgrouting

Electric network is a kind of utility network in GIS. In this network we have a `point` layer that consist power stations and end users. Power stations called `source` and end users called `sink`. And also we have one or more `line` layer that consist power lines. (in the simplest case).

**The direction of this network is from sources to sinks**

My question is how to use `pgRouting` to identify the direct of this network?
pgRouting has function called `pgr_createTopology` that builds a network topology based on the geometry information. When I call this function it fill `source` column and `target` column of my line layer. source and target show the direction of my network. But this direction is not based of source and sink.

In general can we define our own direction in specific network with pgRouting and not use its default direction?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of pgRouting, source and target values of a line are calculated using digitization direction of line.So if u want your direction to be from source to sink. Check the digitization direction of your line segment and where ever it incorrect or in the wrong direction, reverse the digitization direction using ArcMap or QGIS. And then run pgr_createTopology.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with programming instead of using QGIS or ArcMap?

Comment: because source and sink can change periodically